# Guice 3.0 - Which jars do I need for a Swing app with just Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, swing, dependency-injection, guice

Although there is already an answer for `which jars are needed for Guice 2.0`, I haven't found anything for 3.0. I read somewhere that you needed:

```
guice-3.0.jar
aopalliance.jar
javax.inject.jar
```

Can anyone please confirm if this is true, as well as what the other jars give us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those three are enough, unless you wanna use any of the Guice Extensions, like *assisted inject* for example.
Here's a good source of information: [Guice 3.0 Release](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice30)